# why javascript es6 destructuring undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am writing vuex and I like destructuring grammar, but there is an error in the syntax below.
The destructurring variable is undefined, and the normal variable outputs well. What is the reason?

```
[GET_BUSINESS_INFO]: async ({ commit, rootState }) => {
  const { user: { firstBranchId = '' } = {} } = rootState || {};

  console.log('GET_BUSINESS_INFO', rootState.user.firstBranchId);
  // undefined
  console.log('GET_BUSINESS_INFO', firstBranchId);
  // 1
},
```

[image]

Comment: can you add `rootState`?

Comment: yes.


  [GET_BUSINESS_INFO]: async ({ commit, rootState }) => {
    const { user: { firstBranchId = '' } = {} } = rootState;      
    console.log('GET_BUSINESS_INFO', rootState.user.firstBranchId);
    console.log('GET_BUSINESS_INFO', firstBranchId);
    const { result } = await aptc(getBusinessInfo, firstBranchId);
  },

Comment: Sorry. I updated the code.

Comment: rootstate is the grammar of vuex.

Comment: But what is inside that rootState variable? Like it's an object? And what is inside the object? Please provide a runnable code example that can clearly reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `rootState` or `rootState.user` is a proxy, or the `rootState.user` or `rootState.user.firstBranchId` properties are accessor properties with side effects (both unlikely), it's **impossible** for the code you've shown to do what you're saying it does. The only reasonable explanation is that there's something between where the destructuring is done and where the logging is done that changes the state of `rootState`. That change would be shown by your first `console.log`, but not by your second because changing `rootState` after the destructuring won't have any effect on the value in `firstBranchId`. There's *something* in-between the destructuring and the logging. It could be a synchronous function you're calling, or it could be an `await` that causes the `async` function to pause and allows other code elsewhere to run that modifies `rootState` while you're awaiting the promise.

Here's an example of that `async` scenario:

```js
const example = async ({ commit, rootState }) => {
    const { user: { firstBranchId = '' } = {} } = rootState || {};
  
    await something();
  
    console.log('GET_BUSINESS_INFO', rootState.user.firstBranchId); // undefined
    console.log('GET_BUSINESS_INFO', firstBranchId);                // 1
};

function something() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
}

const obj = {
    rootState: {
        user: {
            firstBranchId: 1,
        },
    },
};
const p = example(obj);
obj.rootState.user = {}; // This happens while awaiting `something()`
p.then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

You'll have to look at whatever code is between the destructuring and the logging in order to find out why/where/how `rootState` is being modified.

Comment: Thank you. It was a matter of async wait. It's settled.

Comment: @donghoonlee - Great! I'm glad that helped. :-)